# React-router v5 updates the URL but doesn't render nested component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, connected-react-router

I created an application using `react`, `react-router`, `react-redux`, `connected-react-router` and I have the following structure:

```
- app
  - admin
    - category
      - categoryList
      - categoryAdd
```

My idea is to execute the following app flow:

```
/admin -> /admin/category -> /admin/category/add
```

but for some reason I can't see the last component(`CategoryAdd`) rendered.

Code(sandbox link in the end):

#### index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { Route, Switch, Link } from "react-router-dom"; 
import { ConnectedRouter } from "connected-react-router";
import configureStore, { history } from "./configureStore";

import AdminPage from "./AdminPage";
import Category from "./Category";

const store = configureStore(/* provide initial state if any */);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <>
        <Link to="/admin/category">Category</Link>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/admin" component={AdminPage} />
          <Route exact path="/admin/category" component={Category} />
        </Switch>
      </>
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

#### AdminPage.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default function AdminPage() {
  return (
    <div style={{ border: "1px solid black", margin: 20 }}>
      <div>AdminPage</div>
      <Link to="/admin/category">Catgory page link</Link>
    </div>
  );
}
```

#### Category.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import CategoryList from "./CategoryList";
import CategoryAdd from "./CategoryAdd";

function Category() {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path={`/admin/category`} render={() => <CategoryList />} />
      <Route path={`/admin/category/add`} render={() => <CategoryAdd />} />
    </Switch>
  );
}

export default withRouter(Category);
```

#### CategoryList.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default function CategoryList() {
  return (
    <div style={{ border: "1px solid black", margin: 20 }}>
      CategoryTable <Link to="/admin/category/add">Add</Link>
    </div>
  );
}
```

#### CategoryAdd.js

```
export default function Add() {
  return <div style={{ border: "1px solid black", margin: 20 }}>Add Page</div>;
}
```

Here is the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/embed/dark-star-3fhs0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your using `Switch` which only match one route, so your second routes in `index.js` and `Category` component will never be rendered.

1) Remove `Switch` component and `exact` route props in `index.js`

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <>
        <Link to="/admin/category">Category</Link>
        <Route path="/admin" component={AdminPage} />
        <Route path="/admin/category" component={Category} />
      </>
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

2) Remove `Switch` in `Category`

```
function Category() {
  return (
    <>
      <Route path={`/admin/category`} render={() => <CategoryList />} />
      <Route path={`/admin/category/add`} render={() => <CategoryAdd />} />
    </>
  );
}
```

That works in your code sandbox but your CategoryAdd component is broken because you don't import `React`. So add it in first line :

```
import React from 'react';
```

Result : 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's because of the `exact` keyword on your `/admin/category` route:

```
<Route exact path="/admin/category" component={Category} />
```

This only matches `/admin/category`, but not `/admin/category/add`.

Removing the `exact` will unfortunately only solve your first problem.

The other is your use of `Switch`. You should remove the `Switch` in your `Index.js`, because once you matched your `/admin/category` route, it won't match any of the routes in your Category-Component.